# Is it possible to pass multiple data types inside a JsonDecoder?

Tags: ios, json, swift, protocols, jsondecoder

Here's what I intend to do.

I have two structs, `StructA` and `StructB`.

I also have a JsonDecoder that needs to accept either `StructA` or `StructB`.

I've tried defining a common protocol and conforming both structs to that protocol and tried using the some keyword like:

```
struct StructA: CommonStruct {
   let someBool = false
}

struct StructB: CommonStruct {
   let someString = "SomeString"
}

protocol CommonStruct {
}

func needToGetShitDone(
   data: CommonStruct  // <- What type should ``data`` be? 
) {
   let data = try JsonDecoder().decode(CommonStruct.type, from: data)
}
```

...but of course, that didn't work.

Is it possible to configure the JsonDecoder to accept both StructA and StructB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the protocol conform to `Decodable` and use a generic function

```
protocol CommonStruct: Decodable {}


func decode<T: CommonStruct>(from data: Data) throws -> T {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

Or if you have no other use for your protocol then you can skip it and do

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(from data: Data) throws -> T {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: but how am I supposed to call this function and get the ``Decodable`` object from it? Trying ``let structA: StructA = decode(data)`` returns a **generic pattern T could not be inferred**.

Comment: @PraantoSamadder I am not sure what changes you have made to the function but `let b: StructB = try decode(from: data)` works fine for me with both versions of the function.

Comment: @PraantoSamadder well did my answer help you? If so please mark it as accepted

Comment: I did some further changes to my function and it ended up working. Thanks for your help.